# Unable to validate bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following jquery code

```
$().ready(function){
    $("#Form").validate({
        rules:{
            DL:{
                minlength:2
            }
        }
    });

}   
message:{
    DL:{
        minlength:"DL should be of at least 5";
    }
}
```

The validation required is that the field DL should have length of 5.
The html code is below

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputText">Driving License Number</label><input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="DL" required>
                    </div>
```

But the page does not seem to validate, after clicking a button, instead of showing message the page just scrolls upwards.

Comment: Guessing that's not your full code, since it contains a big syntax error

Comment: Can you tell me where the error is ?

Comment: `$()`, usually you assign that to an object/element; for instance `$(document).ready(`

Comment: `ready(function)` - *ready* should take a function as a parameter; for instance `.ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: I don't even know what that `message : { ... }` goes to

Comment: You should read a getting started in JavaScript book first, before seeking help

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/far1fj1n/

All the code have syntax errors.

And the `$()` should be `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the **rules** object looks for the element's name and you were using the id of the element.

**index.html**

```
<form id="FORM">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputText">Driving License Number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="DL" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#FORM" ).validate({
    rules: {
      DL: {
        required: true,
       minlength: 5
      }
    },
    messages: {
      DL: "DL should be of at least 5"
    }
  });
});
```